# How to create different cross-referencing types

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I need to reference to consecutive points, that sometimes should be conjucted with "and" and sometimes with "or", i.e. either

> 1.1a, b, c and d

or

> 1.1a, b, c or d

Here is an MWE that provides the first type of references (with "and"). However, I am still looking for a way to also have the second type available (with "or"). Is there a way to do so?

```
\documentclass[ngerman, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[german]{cleveref}
\parindent0pt

\labelcrefmultiformat{enumi}%
{\edef\crefstripprefixinfo{#1}#2#1#3}%
{ and~#2\crefstripprefix{\crefstripprefixinfo}{#1}#3}%
{, #2\crefstripprefix{\crefstripprefixinfo}{#1}#3}%
{, and~#2\crefstripprefix{\crefstripprefixinfo}{#1}#3}

\setlist[1]{leftmargin=*}
\setlist[2]{label=\alph*}
\setlist[3]{label=(\roman*)}

\begin{document}

\section{References}

\begin{enumerate}[ref=\thesection.\arabic*]
\item Fruits
\begin{enumerate}[ref=\theenumi\alph*]
\item \label{en:apples} Apples
\item \label{en:bananas} Bananas
\item \label{en:pears} Pears
\item \label{en:ananas} Ananas
\end{enumerate}
\item \label{en:vegetables} Vegetables
\end{enumerate}

The first type of references (with ``and'') works perfectly fine: \labelcref{en:apples,,en:bananas,,en:pears,,en:ananas}.

\end{document}
```